# How to handle Lists with different types

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a function that takes an object as a JSON body and returns a returns the list as a JSON body.

Here is the function:

```
public List<Event> executeRule(Rule rule) {
        List<Transaction> userTransaction = transactionsService.latestTransactionsForUser(rule.getUserId());
        List<Rule> ruleList = activeRulesForUser(rule.getUserId());

       return eventList;
}
```

From the object passed as a parameter I get `userId` and find all transactions and rules for a particular user. Now I have to return those transactions and rules of single user as new list of type `Event`.

What would be the best practice for it as I have two list with different types and third list that I have to return with also different type?

Comment: What have you tried already? What could be a solution in your opinion?

Comment: So this is what I have. I had to get all transactions and rules for the user, and I did it from one parameter that is passed and that is Rule object. This is how far I came to. Now I can't seem to get how to deal with tree lists with different types. Is there any other approach to it?

Comment: That is still the obvious, now, how to proceed from there, what solution can you come up with to create new objects from two different other objects? 
BTW, this seems to be a homework question, and this is not a Homework solution kinda page.

Comment: Well all idea I had was using Java streams. To collect data that I need from both lists.

Comment: In principal a good idea, whereas there is (except readability and performance and other interesting stuff) no real difference to a "usual" loop :-)

Comment: @triplem just found a working solution :) so there was no need for loops or stream.  I just needed to create new Event object populate it and put it in EventList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution.

```
public List<Event> executeRule(Rule rule) {
        List<Transaction> userTransaction = transactionsService.latestTransactionsForUser(rule.getUserId());
        List<Rule> ruleList = activeRulesForUser(rule.getUserId());
        
        List<Event> eEventList = new ArrayList<>();
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setUserId(rule.getUserId());
        savingsEvent.setTransactions(userTransaction);
        savingsEvent.setSavingsRules(savingsRuleList);

        savingsEventList.add(savingsEvent);

       return savingsEventList;
    }
```

So the solution was to create a new object Event and populate it with data that I need from the two lists, then add that object to Event list.

In Event object I added both lists:

```
class Event {

    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    private List<Rule> rules;
    
    //Getters, Setters, Constructors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you want to return the user transactions and rules, if you are encountering these together many times, maybe it's a sign that you should wrap them in a class, as follows:

```
class UserEvents {

    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    private List<Rule> rules;
    
    public UserEvents(List<Transaction> transactions, List<Rule> rules) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public UserEvents() {
        this(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public List<Rule> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    public void setRules(List<Rule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }
}
```

Then your function will look something like this:

```
public UserEvents executeRule(Rule rule) {
    List<Transaction> transactions = transactionsService.latestTransactionsForUser(rule.getUserId());
    List<Rule> rules = activeRulesForUser(rule.getUserId());
    
    return new UserEvents(transactions, rules);
}
```

I would like to let you know that a function with 'execute' in it's name does not really need to return something, it should execute a task or something similar.

You should give descriptive and correct names to your functions and methods, one should understand only from the method decleration what the method does.

Comment: I tried to implement your code but I still have type issues. So execute method return List<UserEvents>. And when I use your code it's still doesnt work in sense of types

Comment: execute method shouldn't return a list of UserEvents but a single object of UserEvents, all the events are listed in the object under props: transactions and rules

Comment: Hi yes it can return a List<Event> I just founded working solution and posted it. I just needed to create new Event object populate it and put it in EventList.